# OpenGL: Is the concept of texture unit redundant?

Tags: opengl, textures

When we want to set a texture as one uniform, we cannot bind a texture id to a program, we have to establish the relationship like below:

textureId  <-> texture unit <-> set Uniform

Is the concept of "texture unit" little redundant?

Is there something special here so that it is useful as an intermediate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits to the number of textures that a shader can access (in theory). These limits are distinct from the limits on the number of uniforms and other parameters that shaders can access.

Furthermore, by making texture objects not be part of program state, it allows you to change programs *without* changing what textures are being used. Two different programs can reference the same texture unit (for example, a shadow map). With your way, we would have to attach the shadow map to every program that uses it. With the current way, we bind it once, and let the programs decide what they use.

Comment: It should be mentioned that texture units and bindings can be circumvented by bindless texture access. Bindless texture access is not part of standard OpenGL, but available through through the `ARB_bindless_texture` extension.

Comment: @datenwolf I thought it became standard in 4.5, or did the Direct State Access stuff not include that?

Comment: @Xirema: Bindless textures are not part of DSA. Bindless textures remain an extension, since [not all 4.x capable hardware can handle them](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_listreports.php?listreportsbyextensionunsupported=GL_ARB_bindless_texture). Or at least, not in that way.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks. "it allows you to change programs without changing what textures are being used." Sorry I don't understand. What does this mean? If we design a system without texture unit, we can still achieve the example you mentioned.

Comment: @user1914692: Only by attaching the texture to every program that needs to use it. This means that every time you change programs, your system will have to rebind that texture because you don't realize that it's already bound. Or at the very least, it'll have to shadow the current texture bindings to prevent such rebinding. Either way, it's more complicated than just doing things the OpenGL way.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new function to make code simpler, because it's maybe redundant but it's also useful :
The texture units is used for multitexturing and there isn't another method to do it so. It's very simple to assign a texture to a number. Then it permit to change texture quickly. So even for only one texture, we have to do this link.

But as i said, a little function which takes the shader program, the texture and perhaps the texture unit then it's ok, only 1 line to make it works.